# nativescript template listview out put is not correct

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

anything wrong from there?

```
<GridLayout rows="*">
    <ListView [items]="tabs">
       <ng-template let-item="tab">
          <Label [text] = "tab.name"></Label>
       </ng-template>
    </ListView>
  </GridLayout>
```

And in my controller:

```
 this.requestService.get('api/config/tabs')
    .subscribe((data:any)=>{

      this.zone.run(() => {
        var results = [];
        data.forEach(item=>{
          results.push({name: item.attributes[0].value , id: item.attributes[0].id });

        });
        this.tabs = results;
       });


    });
```

But why the output is only [Object, Object]

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in the code

Change this

```
<ng-template let-item="tab">
```

to this

```
<ng-template let-tab="item">
```

Comment: Thanks, what a stupid mistake. :-) thanks for pointing out to me

Comment: @nick-iliev, is there any documentation on ng-template? I was tripped up on the same issue.

Comment: This is standard Angular syntax and although it might seem counter-intuitive it makes perfect sense ..image the following `let tab = item;`